# Encoding in Django admin

Tags: django, unicode, encoding, django-admin

In my model I have a field defined like this:

name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Then in admin panel if I try to insert a record with the name that contains characters like 'č', 'š', 'ž', I get the UnicodeEncodeError.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u017e' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is this? Why doesn't django use utf-8 for everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses `utf-8` for everything.  I suppose that the error might be in the `__unicode__()` method of your model.

You should always use the `u'` prefix for all text data.  So if you write something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return 'Model: %s' % self.name
```

then you need to change it to:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Model: %s' % self.name
```

Comment: Btw, my problem was, that I was defining __str__ methods not __unicode__

Comment: As of Django 1.9, there's a `python_2_unicode_compatible` wrapper that deals with this. See the [__str__() bit here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/).