# Django - 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0105' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django

UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/blog/post/add/
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0105' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

When i try to add content via Django admin, i have problem when i using polish letters like śźó...

Comment: ok have solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431108/encoding-in-django-admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431108/encoding-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably coming from your `models.py`

Inside each model, your `def __unicode__(self):` method probably does not return the unicode name correctly. You can fix this by returning a **unicode** .

Example:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{f}'.format(f=self.fieldName)
```

where `fieldName` is the desired thing you want to show inside your django admin panel. If you provide me with your `models.py` I can try and change my example to suit your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's not my view. It's view of django admin template.

Comment: @cpuant does the problem occur when you try to add stuff inside the django admin panel?